# redirect user to homepage after login with microsoft account

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to add a sign-in with Microsoft to an ASP.NET Web application using
[this tuto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-aspnet-webapp). 
The user should be redirected to my app's homepage after entering his microsoft's credentials. But he is redirected to the login page.   I modified the home page ​​and reply URL
values
in Active Directory as https:// localhost:44330/ which is the SSL URL in visual studio.

In the web.config, I have this string:

```
<add key="ida:RedirectUrl" value="https://localhost:44330/" />
```

Need help to figure out please.

Answer (score 1):

After reading through the tutorial myself, I'm wondering if your issue is because of the "ida:" qualifier you have in the key name?

Should it be:

```
<add key="RedirectUrl" value="https://localhost:44330/" />
```

Comment: I agree with @JTech. In the tutorial, the Web.config is created from scratch from  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-aspnet-webapp#step-9-configure-your-webconfig-and-register-an-application whereas if you create a new ASP.NET app it has ida:RedirectUrl

Comment: After debugging, I realized that when the user is successfully authenticated with microsoft, Request.IsAuthenticated and user.identity.IsAuthenticated are always false. Do you have an idea of ​​what is happening?

Comment: If you now have a different issue and this one is resolved, then mark this as answered and ask a new question please.